# Dynamically Adding Listeners To Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, listeners

I'm working on a page which fetches code with a Javascript httpObject and uses it to update two elements on the page - a google map, and a DIV that lists the things the marker points to.

That bit works fine.  The problem is that when I create the markers, I do so through a for loop, and I add listeners to the marker in each loop.  Then, when I test the page, I find the same thing happens for every marker.

Hovering over a marker should change the border colour of the corresponding bit of the DIV.  Instead, each marker changes the border of the last bit.  It seems like each time I add the listeners I overwrite the listeners of the previously added markers too.

I get that this is to do with the Google Maps API retaining the identity of a marker even when you create a new one in Javascript.  What I don't get it how to get around it - I tried creating an array outside the loop, and changing

```
var newMarker = new GMarker(newLatLng);
```

with
    newMarker[count] = new GMarker(newLatLng);

but it still doesn't work.

Help Me, StackOverflow.  You're my only hope. :)

Edit: A little more code

```
for (count=0;count<=LatArray.length;count++)
{
  thisLat = LatArray[count];
  thisLong = LongArray[count];
  thisHTML = HTMLArray[count];
  newLatLng = new GLatLng(thisLat, thisLong, true);

  if (mapBounds.containsLatLng(newLatLng))
  {
      //alert(count);
      var  dinnerNumber = "dinner_"+count;
      newMarkers[count] = new GMarker(newLatLng); 
      map.addOverlay(newMarkers[count]);
      GEvent.addListener(newMarkers[count],'mouseover',function(){document.getElementById(dinnerNumber).style.borderColor = '#000000';
  });
}// for
```

Comment: +1 for referencing Star Wars (the non-rubbish one)

Comment: Can we have a bigger code sample please? It's very hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closure issue -- all those listeners share the same dinnerNumber variable. Try this:

```
GEvent.addListener(newMarkers[count], 'mouseover', (function(dinnerNumber){ return function(){document.getElementById(dinnerNumber).style.borderColor = '#000000';}; })(dinnerNumber));
```

This way, each listener is created with its own closed copy of dinnerNumber.

Comment: Thanks Justin!

I haven't a clue whats going on at the end there, but it works.  I'll pull it apart and see if I can make sense of it, but for now you've solved my problem!

Comment: Check out http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ for a really good explanation of closures and the "infamous loop problem."

Answer (score 1):

You have to read carefully

```
GEvent.addListener(newMarkers[count], 'mouseover', 
       (function(dinnerNumber)
          { return function()
                { document.getElementById(dinnerNumber).style.borderColor = '#000000';};        
          }
      )(dinnerNumber)
);
```

you missed one ();

the 3-rd parameter is (function(var){return function(){//what you want wirh var;};})(var)